# ClickOnce Deployment Website Modification

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce

So I've got an app I want to deploy via ClickOnce.  However, when you visit the deployment webpage, you're treated to a rather bland-ish default-style page with the application name and a "Run" button.  How can I modify this page to have additional buttons, artwork, etc?  I can't seem to find it in my solution anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is auto-generated by the publish wizard, but you don't have to deploy it to your server, just put your own pages there.  There's nothing special about the page that the wizard generates.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is create a web page that points to the application file on the server.  `<a href="http://server/myapp.application">My App</a>`